# dnLib-Generated Assembly - TypeLoadException Thrown at Runtime

Tags: c#, cil, dnlib

I am using [dnLib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib) to generate MSIL assemblies dynamically from a custom language I'm writing, named CSASM:

```cs
string absolute = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), forceOutput ?? $"{asmName}.exe");

ModuleDefUser mod = new ModuleDefUser(asmName, Guid.NewGuid(), new AssemblyRefUser(new AssemblyNameInfo(typeof(int).Assembly.GetName().FullName))){
    Kind = ModuleKind.Console,
    RuntimeVersion = "v4.0.30319"  //Same runtime version as "CSASM.Core.dll"
};
var asm = new AssemblyDefUser($"CSASM_program_{asmName}", new Version(version));
asm.Modules.Add(mod);

// Adding attribute code omitted for brevity

//Adds types to the module and constructs methods and method bodies for those types based on the CSASM source file in question
Construct(mod, source);

mod.Write(absolute);
```

The generation of the executable is working as intended.

However, when trying to run this executable, the `TypeLoadException` below is thrown:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CSASM.Core.IntPrimitive' from assembly
'CSASM_program_Example, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' due to
value type mismatch.
   at Example.Program.csasm_main()
```

`CSASM_program_Example` being the name of assembly for the generated executable, `Example.exe`.

The type `IntPrimitive` is actually found in the `CSASM.Core.dll` assembly, which is also in the same folder as the generated executable.

Due to the extreme lack of documentation surrounding dnLib, I'm essentially stumbling around in the dark here.

---

**In short, is there a reason why the type is trying to be loaded from the wrong assembly?**
If so, is there a way that I can remedy this?

Viewing the assembly in dnSpy shows the `TypeRef`s and `MemberRef`s referencing correct assemblies, which makes this predicament even more frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very thorough examination of a dnLib DLL, the problem was due to me using `Importer.ImportDeclaringType(Type).ToTypeDefOrRef()`, which caused value-type `TypeSig`s to be registered as class-type `TypeSig`s instead.

Even though the docs say to use `Importer.ImportDeclaringType(Type)` over `Importer.ImportAsTypeSig(Type)` for method and field declarations, you really shouldn't be using it.